# Android First App tutorial not working

Tags: android

I'm following the Android developers tutorial to build the first application. I did precisely what it says step by step and completed this page:
 https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Here I get many Java related errors:

```
Description                               Resource             Path                             Location    Type
View cannot be resolved to a type   MainActivity.java   /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 24 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java   /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 25 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type DisplayMessageActivity.java /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 16 Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   DisplayMessageActivity.java /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 20 Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   DisplayMessageActivity.java /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 20 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type MainActivity.java   /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 25 Java Problem
EditText cannot be resolved to a type   MainActivity.java   /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 26 Java Problem
EditText cannot be resolved to a type   MainActivity.java   /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 26 Java Problem
edit_message cannot be resolved or is not a field   MainActivity.java   /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 26 Java Problem
```

Any help please?

EDIT:
@pawalzieba Ok, now I get only these 3 errors:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
edit_message cannot be resolved or is not a field   MainActivity.java   /MyFirstApp/src/com/example/myfirstapp  line 29 Java Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message').  activity_main.xml   /MyFirstApp/res/layout  line 6  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/button_send').   activity_main.xml   /MyFirstApp/res/layout  line 11 Android AAPT Problem
```

Comment: Project setup problem. You have set project folder as your source folder instead of `MyFirstApp/src`

Comment: check strings declarations in probably `res/values.xml` and check R file imports if it's from your application package and not from android package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse:
Right click on project in Package Explorer tab -> "Properties" in dialog -> "Java Build Path" in left menu -> "Source" tab

There you can change source folder. Set it to point on src folder in your project.

---

EDIT

Missing imports in java files. Press in Eclipse this shortcut **Ctrl+Shift+O** to organize imports.

Comment: Check imports of R file. Probably you've imported `android.R` instead `your.application.package.R`.

Comment: Sorry to be so noob, what R file are you referring to? How to do that? A tutorial should work out of the box most of the times... :(

Comment: R file is something like a reference file to resources. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html
The first error is connected probably with it.
The second and third with missing declarations in xml file in res.

Comment: Yes! Now it works. I don't know why I was missing those 2 strings... thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/edit_message').  activity_main.xml   /MyFirstApp/res/layout  line 6  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/button_send').   activity_main.xml   /MyFirstApp/res/layout  line 11 Android AAPT Problem
```

Try to add to strings.xml:

```
<string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
<string name="button_send">Send</string>
```